# What exactly is "libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so" and how to update it?

Tags: raspbian, apt

I recently got a problem involving `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so`: VLC was crashing when calling this library (which overrides memory related functions from `libc6`),  and removing the reference to this library from `/etc/ld.so.preload` fixed the problem.

I thought I might have the wrong version of the library, or perhaps a damaged file, so I tried to reinstall it. To my surprise, `apt-file search libarmmem` returned nothing. I didn't find this library in http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/liba/ or http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/liba/ either.

Does anybody know where this library come from, what functionality does it bring to the table, and how to reinstall it if need be?

Comment: I think it's something to do with `snapd` - based purely on searching for `libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so` on the interwebs

Comment: Not sure WHY it is there, but the library is unchanged since original Buster release.

Comment: @Bravo Now that you say this, I do remember installing snap a while ago. I removed it since though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought I might have the wrong version of the library, or perhaps a damaged file, so I tried to reinstall it. To my surprise, apt-file search libarmmem returned nothing.

Please try the following on a machine with it installed:

```
openhd@openhd-airpi:~$ dpkg -S libarmmem
raspi-copies-and-fills: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
raspi-copies-and-fills: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-aarch64.so
raspi-copies-and-fills: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v7l.so
raspi-copies-and-fills: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v8l.so
openhd@openhd-airpi:~$
```

> what functionality does it bring to the table

It provides things like memcpy and memset tuned for the Arm cores used in Raspberry Pis. Personally, I feel like this was more important with older Pis and maybe a little less so today. From the 2012 version: "Speeds of up to 1390 MB/s have been achieved. This is ~7x faster than the libc version."

> Does anybody know where this library come from,

It used to be on github, but I cannot find it anymore.

> how to reinstall it if need be?

You can remove or install this package: https://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/pool/main/r/raspi-copies-and-fills/

> I recently got a problem involving /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so: VLC was crashing when calling this library (which overrides memory related functions from libc6), and removing the reference to this library from /etc/ld.so.preload fixed the problem.

There was a bug a couple years ago, it was fixed. Do you still have the crash on newer versions?

Comment: Thanks. I must say I can't possibly understand the motivation to name that package `raspi-copies-and-fills` instead of `libarmmem`. They might as well have named it `find-me-i-dare-you` or something similar.